# How to escape quotes in django sql formatting

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following code:

```
# looks like: "('tt1098327','tt3819668','tt0049251')", <type 'str'>
ids_as_string = "(-1)" if not ids else ("('" + "','".join(ids).strip("',") + "')")

items = list(Item.objects.raw("""SELECT * FROM mturk_imdb WHERE (MATCH(name) against(%s)) AND (imdb_id NOT IN %s)""", (q, ids_as_string )))
```

The problem with this is that the sql formatter tries to escape the quotes that I have added in for the tuple:

> DatabaseError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(\'tt1098327\',\'tt3819668\',\'tt0049251\',\'tt3878722\

What would be the correct way to do the above?

Comment: can you show what `ids` is?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? do you want to create a tuple of ids to use as a variable in sql

Comment: why are you joining with a comma and then stripping at the comma again?

Comment: Why are you doing this as raw SQL rather than an ORM query, which would take care of all relevant escaping?

Comment: @DanielRoseman if you can show me how to do it as a regular ORM query I'm all for it -- note there's also a union in the query (not mentioned above) and two limits applied, so not really a straightforward query.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a really stupid approach, but one way would be to combine the two different types of string formatting as follows:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM mturk_imdb WHERE (MATCH(name) against(%s)) AND (imdb_id NOT IN %s) LIMIT 20 UNION SELECT * FROM mturk_imdb WHERE name=%s AND (imdb_id NOT IN %s) LIMIT 30" % ('%s', imdb_ids_as_tuple_str, '%s', imdb_ids_as_tuple_str)
items = list(Item.objects.raw(sql, (q, q)))
```

Where you need the exact unescaped string, you can use `%`, and where you want to escape user inputted data, you can use the `, (params)`.